# Python meta-analysis library

Tags: python, statistics

Is there any python library with functions to perform fixed or random effects [meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis)?

I have search through google, pypi and other sources but it seems that the most popular python stats libraries lack this functionality.

It would be great if it also provide graphical solutions to produce funnel plots and forest plots.

> Forest plot example:

[image]

It thought of something similar to R package [rmeta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmeta/index.html)

I've found some people creating their [own functions manually](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~kshedden/Python-Workshop/probiotic_meta_analysis.html), but it isn't a actual library. In addition, [metasoft](http://genetics.cs.ucla.edu/meta_jemdoc/index.html#download) was promising, but it uses python only to convert between formats.

Comment: Did you take a look at scikit-learn? It provides a lot of tools for statistics and machine-learning. For statistic plot, you could look at seaborn, but I'm not sure it wiil have what you need.

Comment: Actually, I think seaborn as what you need : https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/horizontal_boxplot.html

Comment: Yes,Ii've look at scikit-learn but it doen't provide direct support for meta-analysis. Regarding seaborn it lacks the "Summary measure" that is what a meta-analysis is about, but the horizontal boxplot could be a good start to create my own plot. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just to say, it seems the mostly widely used tool is R's [metafor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor), which provides seemingly every possible method used and includes essential plotting functions.

In Python, [PythonMeta](https://pypi.org/project/PythonMeta) the backend for a web-based tool [PyMeta](http://www.pymeta.com) which offers many of the methods (fixed and random effects, various data types) found in metafor.

This [PyMARE](https://github.com/neurostuff/PyMARE) project is still under development but does provide various fixed and random effects meta-analysis estimators (this is a spin-off from the rather more mature [NiMARE](https://nimare.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tool for neuroimaging meta-analysis).

Answer (score 2):

statsmodels now also offers some options for meta-analysis and visualization of its results, more information here:
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/metaanalysis1.html